# ExpressJS backend with Angular2 CLI

Tags: node.js, express, angular, mean-stack, mean

I'm using Angular2 CLI to generate my ng2 projects.

I want to have Express in the backend and Angular2 CLI (with live reload and auto compile).

How can I seed that project myself also using the Express generator?

In simple ways: I'm looking to create an Express project with the generator and add the Angular2 with the CLI.